# Thin line when rendering overflow:hidden with border-radius

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

To implement some fancy round progress bars, I used an element with border radius and overflow:hidden. Everything looks fine, except one thing: all browsers display a thin line where the overflow ends.

here's some simple snippet that reproduces this bug in all major browsers:

```js
function setMarginLeft(value){
    var element = document.querySelector(".overflowing");
    element.style.marginLeft = value+"px";
}
function setMarginTop(value){
    var element = document.querySelector(".overflowing");
    element.style.marginTop = value+"px";
}
```

```css
.backdrop {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.circle {
  background-color: red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.overflowing {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
input {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="overflowing"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<span>top and right of the circle you should see some red, bottom left not</span><br />
<em>Feel free to play around with these values:</em><br />
Top margin: <input type="number" id="cngMargin" oninput="setMarginTop(this.value)" value="10"><br />
Left margin: <input type="number" id="cngMargin" oninput="setMarginLeft(this.value)" value="10">
```

since the layout isn't nearly as easy as the snippet above, i can't change the layout much.
i guess the essential problem here is the browser's anti-aliasing, which i think is not alterable by css, or is it?

i googled myself stupid on that matter and can't come up with really usefull ressources. i guess if nothing else works, i'll have to do it anew in SVG or on a canvas -.-

Comment: Why do you have `margin-top` and `margin-left` on the `.overflowing` element? Without that I don't see the bleed.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully supported right now but `overflow-clip-margin` could be a solution:

```
overflow: hidden;   // for unsupported browsers
overflow: clip;
overflow-clip-margin: 2px;
```

Note: I don't fully understand your example but for my situation I had a title
bar that was getting a white line around it (inside the border). This is an exaggeration with `overflow-clip-margin: 5px` but if it's only 2px then it matches with the blue border on the white box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems possible without the overlay by using a `background-image` with multiple `linear-gradient`s. The JavaScript to insert the two values into the combined `linear-gradient` is rather clunky as I wrote it hastily to prove the solution. It can be better!

Tested in Chrome only.

```js
var marginTop = marginLeft = 0;

function setMarginLeft(value) {
  marginTop = value;
  applyToCircle();
}

function setMarginTop(value) {
  marginLeft = value;
  applyToCircle();
}

function applyToCircle() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.circle');
  element.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(90deg, red '+ marginTop + '%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(180deg, red '+ marginLeft + '%, transparent 0%)';
}
```

```css
.backdrop {
  background-color:white;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.circle {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
}

input {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
<em>Feel free to play around with these values:</em><br />
Top margin: <input type="number" id="cngMargin" oninput="setMarginTop(this.value)" value="0"><br />
Left margin: <input type="number" id="cngMargin" oninput="setMarginLeft(this.value)" value="0">
```

Comment: as i said, it's not all that simple. my example was just the simplest way to reproduce the error.

Comment: it would have been better to clearly explain exactly which parts of the layout **can** be changed so other people don't waste their time developing solutions which address the stated issue of removing the _thin line where the overflow ends_